# How to divide date in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, division

Is it possible to divide a date in Excel?

Example:

If a date is 20/08/2021 then adding 10 days to it

& result has to be divided by 2

Comment: And what should be the expected result?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to divide a date, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without problem:

Imagine in a cell (D3) you put "20/08/2021", and then you say:

```
E3 : =D3 + 10
E4 : =E3 / 2
E5 : 0 (formatted as date)
```

This is what you will get:

```
E3 : 30/08/2021 (dates are counted with a single day as 1)
E5 : 00/01/1900 (Excel dates start at "zero" january 1900)
E4 : 30/10/1960 : apparently the date in the middle of "30/08/2021" and 
                  "00/01/1900" is calculated.
```

If you want to use the division to calculate the day in the middle of, let's say January first and March first, you can do this:

```
=(DATE(2021,1,1)+DATE(2021,3,1))/2
```

And you'll see it's not February first, but January 30.